# NLTK letter 'u' in front of text result?

Tags: nltk

I'm learning NLTK with a tutorial and whenever I try to print some text contents, it returns with 'u' in front of it.

In the tutorial it looks like this,

firefox.txt Cookie Manager: "Don't allow sites that set removed cookies to se...

But in my result, it looks like this

(u'firefox.txt', u'Cookie Manager: "Don\'t allow sites that set removed cookies to se', '...')

I am not sure why. I followed exact way the tutorial is explaining. Can someone help me understand this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Before using NLTK, you should definitely learn Python e.g. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ or at least https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: I learned python, but just didn't understand why it was showing the leading'u'. I probably didn't try to learn NLTK if I didn't know python. I actually used exact book that you recommended.

Answer (score 3):

That leading `u` just means that that string is Unicode. All strings are Unicode in Python 3. The parentheses means that you are dealing with a tuple. Both will go away if you print the individual elements of the tuple, as with `t[0]`, `t[1]`, and so on (assuming that `t` is your tuple).

If you want to print the whole tuple as a whole, removing `u`'s and parentheses, try the following:

```
print " ".join (t)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway that I can remove when I print? For example, when I tried to do brown.categories(), brown is another corpus, it also displays with leading 'u'. Or should I just ignore it?

Comment: Going to expand the above answer!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answer the leading **u** just means that string is Unicode. **str()** can be used to convert unicode to str but there doesnt seem to be a direct way to convert all the values in a tuple from unicode to string.
Simple function as below and using it when ever you are referring to any tuple in nltk.

```
>>> def str_tuple(t, encoding="ascii"):
...    return tuple([i.encode(encoding) for i in t])
>>> str_tuple(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.fileids())
```

('austen-emma.txt', 'austen-persuasion.txt', 'austen-sense.txt', 'bible-kjv.txt', 'blake-poems.txt', 'bryant-stories.txt', 'burgess-busterbrown.txt', 'carroll-alice.txt', 'chesterton-ball.txt', 'chesterton-brown.txt', 'chesterton-thursday.txt', 'edgeworth-parents.txt', 'melville-moby_dick.txt', 'milton-paradise.txt', 'shakespeare-caesar.txt', 'shakespeare-hamlet.txt', 'shakespeare-macbeth.txt', 'whitman-leaves.txt')

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Python2.6 or any version before 3.0.

Python allows its users to do the same operation on 'str()' and 'unicode' in the early version. They tried to make conversion between 'str()' and 'unicode' directly in some case rely on default encoding, which on most platform is ASCII. That's probably the reason cause your problem. Here are two ways may solve it:

First, manually assign decoding method. For example:

```
>> for name in nltk.corpus.gutenberg.fileids():
>>     name.decode('utf-8')
>>     print(name)
```

The other way is to UPDATE your Python to version 3.0+ (Recommended). They fix this problem in Python3.0. Here is the link to update detail description:
https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit

Hope this helps you.